# How to start Fuseki server using Java code and upload OWL file to it using java code?

Tags: java, cmd, jena, owl, fuseki

I want to start Fuseki server using Java code.Then I want to upload OWL file into it. Now I started using following CMD code and manually upload the file.Is there any possible way to do it using Java code?
Server starting code using CMD.

```
    D:
    cd Fuseki
    cd jena-fuseki-1.0.1
    fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

Is there any possible way to run above code in JAVA code and upload a OWL file into Fuseki server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a Fuseki SPARQL server using the Apache Jena Java API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488196/how-do-you-create-a-fuseki-sparql-server-using-the-apache-jena-java-api)

Comment: **Is there any possible way to run above code in JAVA code and upload a OWL file into Fuseki server?** The answer to the other question says "yes, but it's not really supported." You didn't show any particular attempt or mention any technical difficulty, so aside from that, we can't really help more than that.

Comment: Also see [How do I start a Fuseki server from Jena API Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24971291/1281433) wherein AndyS points out that you can simply call fuseki's main method directly (just like any other Java application).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you.I will see. Because of no knowledge about Maven and other things I have to look at those things.Actually If can provide possible way to run above code in java class. Currently every time when I want to server start I copy those things to CMD and run.

Answer (score 1):

The core idea of the solution is to use Jena ARQ API.
You need to use class `com.hp.hpl.jena.query.DatasetAccessor` and `.putModel()` method.

This blog https://pinesong.ghost.io/how-to-upload-rdf-file-to-jena-fuseki-server-using-java-code  gives the details.

Comment: The link https://pinesong.ghost.io/how-to-upload-rdf-file-to-jena-fuseki-server-using-java-code returns "Site Unavailable"

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the fuseki as an embedded server. You can either opt for persistance using a triplestore TDB that Jena comes with or you can create an in-memory model. I'll show the case for the former but the idea remains the same for the latter.

```
//Creating a persistent triple store (Jena TDB)
String dir = "C:\\..."; // triplestore directory
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(dir);

//Loading an ontology stored on the disk
String ontDir = "C:\\...ontology.owl"; //Directory of your OWL file
Model graph = RDFDataMgr.loadModel(ontDir);

dataset.addNamedModel("..GraphURI..", graph);

// Starting the fuseki server
FusekiServer fusekiServer = FusekiServer.create()
            .port(3001)
            .add("/ds", dataset, true)
            .build();

fusekiServer.start();
```